# Automating npm and webpack with Phonegap build

Tags: npm, webpack, phonegap-build

I'm building a PhoneGap app with PhoneGap build. I'd like to sync the app with my Git repository at BitBucket. The problem is that I ignore the files that are in my node_modules folder and the dist files that are generated by WebPack. So I want to automatically run an npm install and webpack before PhoneGap builds the app.

I have looked into hooks, and they seem like exactly what I need. However, I can't seem to get them to work. For example, I made a folder hooks/before_build and placed a test script in there that just echos back the word "test". But I don't see the output of that anywhere in the build log. I also added it specifically to my config.xml without any output.

It seems unusual that I haven't been able to find anywhere that explains this, but I can't seem to find anywhere.

Could anyone share how they have their build system set up, or provide relevant links?